# Android APK with large resource files

Tags: java, android, resources, apk, bundle

I am developing OCR application and it has large size of resources which are copy from Computer directory into app folder using gradle build file. But it is generating very large size apk when im generating apk. What is the workaround I have to do for testing purpose when I install apk manually on my device through file storage and later for google play store.

Comment: so what you need to do? is it your Question???

Comment: if you wanted to say that you are looking for a way to speed up debug installation - try using instant run. If you are looking for the way to overcome Google Play APk size limit (50 MB), you can use expansion APKs: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Yes what I could do and how @yuvrajsinh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you formatted your question, the answers you will get will be **opinion based**.

IMO:

**During Developement**:
Transfer the recourses you need from your pc to the device's external storage. (I.E. in `downloads` folder or something similar. I am not talking about any `SD` here.). This will be a time saver as you won't need to transfer these files everytime you build and re-run your app.

**During Production**:
I would suggest to not include the resources in your apk at all to achieve a small app size. Have the recourses reside on some `server` and implement some logic where the user downloads **only what he needs when/if he needs it**.

Comment: Thank you! Basically im using **OCR I.R.I.S Idrs sdk** for image to searchable pdf conversion and it is copying lots of resources just for simplicity to for starting point of development. All these files are necessary for application. Your opinion based ans gave me some path to start with. Could you please share any process code which i run on start of app and copy resources and **jniLibs** from particular directory to **app assets folder or any other folder**.